# Using Variable in JSON object Name

Tags: jquery, json, string, variables, object

I've been searching for a solution for this but I can't seem to come up with an answer, so hoping someone on here can help.

I have this JSON string stored in a cookie like so:

```
$.cookie('serviceTrip', JSON.stringify(serviceTrip));
```

I need to extract a value from this cookie based on a certain variable "n" that changes based on user input.
What I have is:

```
var n = 3;
var serviceTripValues = JSON.parse($.cookie('serviceTrip'));
var serviceTripStartValue = 'serviceTrip'+n+'start';
alert(serviceTripStartValue); //this produces serviceTrip3start
alert(JSON.parse($.cookie('serviceTrip')).serviceTrip3start); // this produces 12:00 as expected
alert(JSON.parse($.cookie('serviceTrip')).serviceTripStartValue); // this produces 'undefined'
```

I cant figure this out... I think it has something to do with the fact that serviceTripStartValue is a string and not an object but I don't know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
alert(JSON.parse($.cookie('serviceTrip'))[serviceTripStartValue]);
```

Comment: OMG - that was it!  I've been banging my head on this.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You're already parsing the cookie contents, no need to do it twice:

```
alert(serviceTripValues[serviceTripStartValue]);
```

The reason your attempt didn't work is because you're treating `serviceTripValues` as if it were this:

```
serviceTripValues = {
    serviceTripStartValue:'12:00'
}
```

...when in fact, it's this:

```
serviceTripValues = {
    serviceTrip3start:'12:00'
}
```

Using array notation allows JavaScript to interpret the `String` stored in `serviceTripStartValue` instead of treating it as a literal object key.

Cheers

Comment: Yes - thanks for the added clarification.  I think i understand what the problem was now.... and i won't be parsing the cookie twice, that was just for demonstration purposes.